# Авторизовался в вк с помощью специальной библиотеки на пайтон

Tags: python, парсер, вконтакте, авторизация

Задача у меня такая, нужно спарсить плейлисты, но без авторизации не пускает. Я авторизовался с помощью кода ниже, но продолжая после этого работу, всё равно вылазит окошко с авторизацией. Что я не так делаю, подскажите пожалуйста.

```
api = vk.API(access_token=Config.acces_token)
```

Вот авторизация. А дальше как работать с этим не понимаю. В официальную документацию смотрел, там методы, которые мне не нужны.

Answer (score 0):

Использовал не ту библиотеку. Установил vk_api. Авторизация выглядит вот так:

```
session = vk_api.VkApi(login=Config.login, password=Config.password)
session.auth()
```